# jQuery удалить блок и вставить вместо него другой

Tags: jquery

Код AJAX запроса, который удаляет пост из БД и в случае успешного удаления из БД блок с постом (`div class="post"`) удаляется со страницы

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-post', function(){
    var $btn = $(this);
    var post_id = $(this).closest('.post').data('post-id');

    $btn.prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/delete',
        data: {'id' : post_id},
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(response){ 
            if(response.success) {
              $btn.closest('.post').remove();
            }
            if(response.fail) {

            }
            $btn.prop('disabled', false); 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            $btn.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Командой `$btn.closest('.post').remove();` пост удаляется со страницы со списком постов. Как можно не просто удалять пост, но вставлять на его место другой блок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1) Можно сначала добавлять новый элемент, а потом удалять старый:***

```
$btn.closest('.post').after('Новый элемент').remove(); // Добавить элемент вперёд
```

Или

```
$btn.closest('.post').before('Новый элемент').remove(); // Добавить элемент назад
```

***2) Можно заменить DOM элемента:***

```
$btn.closest('.post').get(0).outerHTML = 'Новый элемент';
```

<sup>Это JS функция, по этому нужно указывать индекс</sup>

*JQuery:*

```
$btn.closest('.post').replaceWith('Новый элемент');
```

Comment: А  можно как-то вынести добавление элемента в отдельную функцию? Потому что там будет добавляться блок с контентом и вложенными блоками, и просто чтобы можно было использовать эту функцию много раз?

Comment: @Heidel, можешь тем же `before/after`, только перед этим создать новый элемент (К примеру: `var new = $('<div>Это к пример</div>')`). Добавляешь его так: `$btn.closest('.post').after(new).remove();`, а потом в дальнейшем обращаешься к нему через переменную `new`.

Comment: Yuri ,не,это понятно,что так можно, но вот можно как-то сделать функцию, куда передавать разметку блока плюс еще текст сообщения в этом блоке и в нужном месте вызывать эту функцию чтобы она блок с разметкой и сообщением вставляла в нужном месте? у меня собственно затык как раз в том,  как это все вставлять в нужное место ( вместо удаленного `.post`)

Comment: @Heidel, а чем тебе прошлые варианты не подходят для этой функции?Можно, правда, вычислить ID элемента по всему документу и вставлять уже по ID в нужно место

Comment: @Heidel , `function replaceContent(id, content) { $('#' + id).get(0).outerHTML = content; }`

Comment: @br3t мне не контент нужно заменять, а блок целиком

Comment: @Heidel, outerHTML - это блок целиком. Для замены ещё есть стандартная функция JQuery: `replaceWith`. Я недавно написал функцию основанную на этой. [Ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/f9Lxgsze/)